# Decrease column value via update query with join clause using CI's active record

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, sql-update, inner-join

I have two tables:

`table1`: `id`, `user_id`, `poll_id`, `options_id`

`table2`: `id`, `poll_id`, `votes`

The column `votes` is an integer and I want to change the value by joining the tables with some where clauses:

```
$this->db
->set('votes', 'votes - 1', FALSE)
->join('table1', 'poll_votes.options_id = table2.id')
->where('poll_id', $row)
->where('user_id', $id)
->update('table2');
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Error Number: 1054
Unknown column 'user_id' in 'where clause'
UPDATE `table2` SET votes = votes - 1 WHERE `poll_id` = '9' AND `user_id` = '1'
```

Comment: Check again the user_id column name if it the same like in DB table!

Comment: yes, it´s same @ErmanBelegu

Comment: Try echouing your last query and put it into database via phpmyadmin. `echo $this->db->last_query();`And maybe post it here as well

Answer (score 9):

Try this one:

```
$this->db->set('votes', 'votes - 1', FALSE)
$this->db->where('table1.user_id',$id);
$this->db->where('table2.poll_id',$row);
$this->db->update('table1 join table2 ON table1.poll_id= table2.poll_id');
```

Comment: just update this part `$this->db->update('table1 join ON table1.poll_id= table2.poll_id');` with `$this->db->update('table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.poll_id= table2.poll_id');`

Answer (score 0):

try this out. It worked for me!!!

```
$data = array(
    'a.ED_FName' => $_POST['firstname'],
    'a.ED_MName' => $_POST['middlename'],
    'a.ED_LName' => $_POST['lastname'],
    'a.ED_Location' => $_POST['location'],
    'a.ED_Company' => $_POST['company'],
    'b.EMD_Department' => $_POST['department']
);

$this->db->set($data);

$this->db->where('a.EmpID', $empID);

$this->db->where('b.EmpID', $empID);

$this->db->update('tbl_employeedetails as a, tbl_employeementdetails as b');
```

Best Regards,
TUSHAR NIRAS

**Update:**

***Note:*** Never Use Global Arrays Like $_POST, $_GET Containing User's Request Data Directly Without Security Checks. This Can Lead to Serious Issues Like SQL Injections.