# How can I UPDATE Table A in MySQL joining another table?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, join

I have a `stats` table that has a `user_id`.
I have a `users` table with an `id` that corresponds to the above `user_id`. I also have an `employee` flag in the `users` table.

I want to update all records in the `stats` table where the `user_id` is not that of an employee.

Ideally, I'd like to do this via the `CodeIgniter Active Record`, but I'm fine with a raw query as well.

Thanks!

**EDIT** My attempt

```
if($employee == false) {
  $this->db->where('(default_profiles.opid = 0 OR default_profiles.opid IS NULL)');  
} else {
  $this->db->where('default_profiles.opid > 0');
}
$this->db->join('weekly_stats', 'default_weekly_stats.user_id = default_profiles.user_id');

$this->db->update('default_weekly_stats', $data);
```

However, this just yields:

```
UPDATE `default_weekly_stats` SET `rank` = 1 WHERE `default_weekly_stats`.`week` = '1' AND `default_weekly_stats`.`correct_picks` = '4' AND (default_profiles.opid = 0 OR default_profiles.opid IS NULL)
```

Comment: Try this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17950763/codeigniter-active-record-update-with-join/17954530#17954530

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tried it but maybe it should be like this:

```
$this->db->where_not_in('users.employee_flag', '0')->join('users', 'users.user_id = stats.user_id')->update('stats', $data);
```

**EDIT: ( based on @dianuj answer )**

```
$this->db->set('rank', $rank );
if($employee == false) {
  $this->db->where('(default_profiles.opid = 0 OR default_profiles.opid IS NULL)');  
} else {
  $this->db->where('default_profiles.opid > 0');
}
$this->db->update('weekly_stats ON default_weekly_stats.user_id = default_profiles.user_id');
```

Comment: I updated my question to show an example of what I tried. Similar to what you suggested, but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
update stats s
inner join users u on u.id = s.user_id
                   and u.employee = 0
set some_column = 'some_value'
```